# Sorting =QUERY() data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I work at a music school where the scheduling system is rather... offensive? Archaic. They basically have a spreadsheet for each teacher that they update manually and it's a time-consuming nightmare. So I'm trying to help.

My fantasy is this:

Right now I have a master roster of all students and ideally I'd like that to be the only spreadsheet that gets edited. It contains everything about each student, such as their lesson time, instrument, name, etc.

Then I have a schedule sheet for each teacher, which I'd like to be automatically maintained based on the data in the master roster. So I'd like the schedule sheet to search through the master roster, find all the students associated with that teacher, pull the data about each student (name, lesson times, etc.), and populate the schedule sheet automatically as students are added or subtracted.

I've researched quite a bit here and it looks like I can use a =QUERY() function to get the data, but the trick is that I need the students in chronological order by their lesson times, and ideally with gaps where gaps in time are. Basically, when I add a new student to the master roster I'd like the schedule sheet to look at the lesson start time, automatically create a new row in the appropriate place and under the correct weekday on the schedule sheet, populate the row with the data, and if there is a gap between the end time and start time of two consecutive lessons, I'd like it to add a blank row so that it's visually obvious where the openings are. If a new lesson is scheduled that closes that gap, the blank row would be deleted, and if a student is removed from the schedule, their row would also be deleted and replaced with a blank row (or ideally a row that says "OPEN").

So my question is: How can I tell the queried data to sort itself chronologically, while leaving or adding a blank row in the gaps where the numbers aren't consecutive?

I would appreciate any and all help! I've already searched around but I'm not entirely sure what to search for.

Thanks!

Comment: I performed a similar task years ago with sales sheet from different salespeople, which build a unique file with all data from the sheet. In this case, the sheet from vendors were updated separately, and the boss could check data from all sellers. You'd probably will get downvoted because of your question (it does not ask for solving a specific problem, you are asking for general references). Be careful!

Comment: You might want to join this Google plus group:  [Apps Script Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)

Comment: Hm, thanks fabrosell, I'll edit and rephrase.

Comment: Thanks, Sandy, I'll look into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the resource I need! It explains how to order the query but it sounds like adding a blank row between time gaps would be much more complicated - haven't figured that out yet.

https://anandexcels.wordpress.com/2013/11/01/query-function-in-google-sheets/

Comment: the official google help for query is also just as good